# How do i obtain a nested div id value in an li class in javascript + html

Tags: javascript, html

I need my javascript `dropDownFunction()` to select the correct `div` container when the user clicks on a given button. Right now it will always open the drop down menu for the `myDropdownTop` container, but I need the function to be able to open `myDropdownBottom` if the user clicks that button.

I am confused on how to get that unique id, like `myDropdownBottom` or `myDropdownTop`, etc.

I tried using `getElementsbyClassName` but I couldn't figure out how to get the variables to work together with the function.

```html
<ul class="matchup">
    <li class="team team-top">
        <button onclick="dropDownFunction()" class="btn"><span class="seed">01</span><span id="team1">&nbsp;</span><span class="score">&nbsp;</span></button>
    </li>
    <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
        <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button>
        </br>
        <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button>
        </br>
        <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button>
        </br>
    </div>
    <li class="team team-bottom">
        <button onclick="dropDownFunction()" class="btn"><span class="seed">32</span><span id="team1">&nbsp;</span><span class="score">&nbsp;</span></button>
    </li>
    <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
        <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button>
        </br>
        <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button>
        </br>
        <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button>
        </br>
    </div>
</ul>
```

```
function dropDownFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdownTop").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Comment: First, I think you have a problem with you `html` code. It seems that the `div`s are outside the `li` definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should include the div in the same element as the button, so that you have a way to know which `button` corresponds to which `div`.

Once you do that you can loop through your 2 groups and add an event listener to each `button` that will trigger the respective `div`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("li.team").forEach(function(teamDom) {
  teamDom.querySelector("button.drop-down-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    teamDom.querySelector("div.dropdown-content").classList.toggle("show");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content:not(.show) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="matchup">
  <li class="team team-top">
    <button class="btn drop-down-btn"><span class="seed">01</span><span id="team1">&nbsp;</span><span class="score">&nbsp;</span></button>
    <div id="myDropdownTop" class="dropdown-content">
      <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
      <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
      <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="team team-bottom">
    <button class="btn drop-down-btn"><span class="seed">32</span><span id="team1">&nbsp;</span><span class="score">&nbsp;</span></button>

    <div id="myDropdownBottom" class="dropdown-content">
      <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Change Team</button></br>
      <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Establish Winner</button></br>
      <button class="open-button" onclick="openFormPF()">Set Score</button></br>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where are the first two boxes of code supposed to be used? Are you saying to place that in my dropDownFunction()?

Comment: @tonytone First two boxes? Do you mean the JavaScript and CSS part? You either put them in their `script` and `style` block or reference them from a `script` or `link` block respectively.